# Как с помощью htmlagilitypack парсить комментарии к коду?

Tags: c#, htmlagilitypack

Нужно парсить текст находящийся в тегах

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack разве "видит" комментарии, а не пропускает их? Парсер же работает по DOM куда комментарии по понятным причинам не входят. Мне кажется, что без регулярок вам здесь не обойтись.

Comment: Приведите пример того, что нужно парсить и что нужно получить.

Answer (score 0):

По идее, комментарии выбрать можно так:

```
htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//comment()")
```